# How to force a process to run on a single thread only with numactl?

Tags: linux

My local machines has multiple CPUs, each has multiple cores, and each can support multiple threads. I have a multithreading process that I want to force to run on a single thread only. I understand `numactrl` can do that.

How can I use `numactl` to force the process to run only on a single thread? Alternatively, is there an even simpler built-in utility that can do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
numactl --physcpubind=+1 /path/to/your/executable
```

this should run your process on the second core/cpu assigned to your chipset (index 1). 
see the Examples section of the man page for more details:
http://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl

Edit:
I should point out, that this means the program will run at most one thread concurrently, but it does not mean that the entire process will be composed of only one thread. if the program is written to spawn a new thread, it will do so, but it will execute on the same core/cpu as the rest of the process. a slim distinction, but potentially important nonetheless.

Comment: Is there some way to force the program to single thread no matter how it is written? TIA!!

Comment: No. the creation of a thread is code that is specifically written into the program (in most languages and frameworks) so the program will create as many threads as its code dictates. the system may be configured to allow only one thread concurrently, but that just means that the cpu will time-slice between threads. some apps may interrogate the OS for information when deciding when/if to create a second thread, but that is up to the program.

Comment: @AayushSingla, there is, `prlimit`, see my answer here https://superuser.com/a/1699657/1264656

Answer (score 4):

To limit program to one CPU hardware core/thread one may also use `taskset 1 prog [args]`

P.S.

The program to limit number of processes a program can have (threads) is `prlimit --nproc=1 prog [args]`. I've tried to use it with `rsync` and got "fork unavailable... error in IPC" and the end - `rsync` is written not to work as one thread.

```
strace prlimit --nproc=1 rsync
```

Running `strace` has shown as described in SO link below return value from `clone` call is `-1 EAGAIN (resource temporary unavailable).`

P.S. idea taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637451/is-there-a-way-force-a-program-to-use-only-1-thread.